# Integrating factor for first order differential equations: using $x$ versus $e^{\ln x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{y}{x}=e^x$$

why is $\mu(x)=x$ the integrating factor as opposed to $\mu(x)=e^{\ln(x)}$? Thanks!

Comment: Because $e^{\ln x}$ simplifies to $x$...

Comment: What I am really asking is... Is it wrong to use $e^{ln(x)}$ as my integrating factor?

Comment: They are the _same thing_. Use which ever one you want, although its a better idea to use $x$ as it is simplified.

Comment: Not wrong, but... you are going to integrate some stuff involving it, right? And that is going to be pretty much impossible unless you simplify.

Comment: Ok, just making sure. This was a terrible question now that I think about it.

Comment: Don't worry about it; we've seen worse. :)

Comment: Brain fart! :P Thanks guys. I'll go hide now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $e^{ln(x)} = x$

Need me to go further?

It is completely fine to use $e^{ln(x)}$, though.

Comment: Haha no, I guess that was a very silly question after all.

Comment: Better to use $\frac{3e^{\ln x}}{3}$.

Comment: @vadim123 Yes, that is better. But, $e^{ln(x)}$ is also valid.